# sql search for string and get all rows content

Tags: mysql, qt

Hi I need to search a string in data base and if the string is there get the entire row, I need to do this in QT.

currently I am using this query to get the data

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number MATCH '2222'
```

where number is the column where all the number data stored.

Here is the code in Qt,

```
QString text = "2222";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
if(db.open()){
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.exec("SELECT * FROM table WHERE number MATCH '"+text+"'");
}
```

But no data I am getting after executing the query.
What I need is retrieve all the rows from the data base, if the row `number` contain the string `2222`

Comment: Wildcards: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE number LIKE '%"+text+"%'"`

Comment: Hi thanks, that's works fine. btw why the % symbol, I am first time with mysql

Comment: `%` means "match anything"

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks one more.

Comment: `MATCH` is used only for searching full-text indexes in mysql. So you have to use `LIKE` as mentioned already.

Comment: @AlexK. I have one more query suppose my DB contain large amount of data similar to my keyword I am searching, then is it possible to limit the the search count say 50

Comment: Lookup the `LIMIT` keyword

Comment: Then is it currect the start index set 0 like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE number LIKE '%"+text+"%' limit 0,50"`, I have tested it and seems working, but I just want to confirm it.

Comment: Yes (or just `LIMIT 5`) - Remember this is basically a random set of 5 rows that match the `LIKE` clause; you must have an `ORDER BY` to make them non-random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number LIKE '%"+text+"%'";
```